The laravel errors are not shown correctly
I'm creating a Laravel app with membership. I'm using breeze to manage that. Recently I've added the verification e-mail function and from here, my error messages are not shown correctly.
For example, if the authentication failed, normally the app have to show "The e-mail or the password provided are not corresponding" and now the app just show "auth.failed".
I don't know if it's related to the e-mail verification function that i've added recently, but I have never seen this issue.
Thank you for your help
I have try to see if there is an array created by breeze with the error messages like this :
$messages = array(
    'email.required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
);

And I didn't find anything.
I don't know where breeze write the error messages, so I have not done a lot of things.

sounds like you are missing the transaction files, or your service provider in not registering them

Okey, Thank you. And how can I add the transaction file or verify the provider ?

meant to say **translations

Ok, so the messages are used like translations ? But I don't use them and I don't have a lang folder in my project. So do I have to publish something in vendor or how can I access the files ?

do you have an auth.php file in resources/lang/en

I don't have a folder named resources/lang/ I don't use translation in my app

did you do php artisan breeze:install when installing breeze?

Yes, and I redone it just to know if that was the error. Nothing changes, I still not have an auth.php file in /ressources/lang/

So do you have an idea of what is going on ?

https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/tree/main

do php artisan lang:publish to create the lang folder ref. On config\app.php check the locale if is en, you must have a folder like \en inside the \lang.  If The message is auth.failed then in lang\en\auth.php  you must have a key like 'failed'   => 'These credentials do not match our records.',

So I have discovered what was wrong. I had just try to change the lang in the .env file, but I have not create a lang file for this. As it was a test I think I forgot to put the initial parameters.
So You can close this answer.
Thank you for your help :)
